# Line graph with multiple axes matplotlib

Tags: python, file, matplotlib, plot

Is it possible to have a below given like plot with Python matplotlib ? one axis and multiple lines I know how to plot. But can we have one plot with `2 x axes` and `2 y axes` for same line graph. [image]

Data input format: Particular count at particular time in a particular lat and lon.

```
[0]   [1]      [2]       [3]
3123 12:00:01 73.789561 19.997404 
5342 12:15:00 73.780732 19.994279 
4515 12:15:30 73.785531 19.994191 
4515 12:00:20 73.786610 19.993679 
6265 12:10:10 73.784650 19.997702

col[0] int count 
col[1] time interval
col[2] longitude
col[3] latitude 

X1 = col[0]
y1 = col[1]
x2 = col[3]
y2 = col[2]
```

How can I have all the 4 axes in one line plot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ax.twinx()` and `ax.twiny()` to accomplish what you are after.  Take a look at [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html), it should get you on the right path.